# Git merge not giving the files from Main

Tags: git

I am working with git and visual studio. I have my local branch, remote branch and main(parent).

After a week of work, I did a merge from main (from visual studio but something like `git merge main`)

I got 100 files, i resolved 1 file (so didnt resolved technically, took their change and edited mine on top)

Just committed my local changes first and from VS i unstaged all the files I got from merge and did an undo on those files (thought I will do git merge main again)

Now, when I do `git merge main` I just get all files are up to date. Git is thinking it gave me all the files from parent, but I had it, i did an undo from VS and now i am unable to get those 100 files. How to get that ?

Note : Nothing on my local that I need to save. And dont want to create a new branch because of existing code review changes.

I also tried `git reset --hard origin/local`

Comment: You can use `git reflog` to see your git changes history. If you find a desired ref, you can do `git reset --hard <REF_SHA>`. After undoing, please provide more details and show the output of `git branch -a`.

Answer (score 2):

When you perform a merge, you are creating two things: a new version of the *content* of your repository, and some *metadata* about what's been merged. When you started the merge process, git got ready to record the *metadata*, and paused while you sorted out the *content*.

Then this happened:

> Just committed my local changes first and from VS i unstaged all the files I got from merge

This changed the *content* that would be included in the commit, but it didn't change the *metadata*. So when you committed, you were still committing a merge, not a "normal" commit.

An important thing to keep in mind here is that git doesn't version *files*, it versions *the whole tree at once*. A commit is a snapshot of that tree, plus some metadata, which includes its "parents". A merge commit therefore can't record which *files* were merged, only which *commits* were used to produce the result.

Now, when you ask to do the merge again, git is looking for commits which aren't already in the history of your current branch; it finds the merge commit you created, and sees that all the commits you're hoping to merge are already on one side of it, so don't need merging.

The solution is to *rewrite history* - create an alternative reality where you didn't perform this merge, but did commit your local changes.

0. Make sure you have no uncommitted changes. If you have, save them somewhere like `git stash`.
1. Use `git log` or a graphical tool to find the commit hash of the merge commit (let's call it "M") and the last commit made on your branch before the merge (let's call it "B").
2. Reset your branch to commit "B" with `git reset --hard B`. This rewinds the branch, and discards everything after that point from your working copy.
3. Check out all the *content* from commit "M", without any *metadata*, using `git restore --source=M .` (or, I think, `git checkout M .` on older versions of git before the more intuitive `restore` and `switch` commands were added)
4. You should now have the changes from the "not really a merge" as uncommitted changes. Commit them now.
5. Perform the merge again - and this time, don't discard the changes you want to keep. :)

Comment: @IMSop On step 3, you mean `source=M` right ?

Comment: @TTT Yes, well spotted!

Comment: @meh Yes, sorry

Comment: @IMSoP I tried git checkout M and I got message like `You are in the detached HEAD state. You can look around, make experimental changes and commit them and you can discard any commits you make in this state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch. 

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may do by -c.  git switch -c <new-branch-name> or undo this operation with git switch -.      HEAD is now at M Changes for code review comments.`

Comment: Now, when I go to VS, I can see the detached CL. That detached CL also doesnt contain the merge info that I had. So VS build is breaking

Comment: @meh If the output is mentioning `git switch`, then git is new enough to have `git restore` and you don't need to navigate the confusing subtleties of `git checkout` (look carefully and you'll see I wrote `git checkout M .` - that `.` is significant). I've no idea what "the detached CL" means, but to get back, just run `git switch -` as the message says, then carry on at step 3.

Comment: This works. But when i try to commit (it works) and then when I try to push, it say pull before push. And when I pull it removes the changes again

Comment: @meh Read up on "rewriting history" and "force push".